# How can a .NET assembly detect its own version within an IIS ASP.NET context?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a c# function that works great in a winforms app to detect its container DLL's version as stamped in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
private string getVersion() {
  System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
  FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
  string tempFileVersion = fvi.FileVersion;

  if (tempFileVersion.EndsWith(".0")) {
    return tempFileVersion.Substring(0, tempFileVersion.Length - 2);
  } else {
    return tempFileVersion;
  }
}
```

The problem is, this function throws exceptions when it's called as part of an ASP.NET webapp in IIS. I'm assuming it comes down to permissions problems, but is there a way for a function to ask the DLL it lives in "what is your version" inside an IIS context?

Comment: That code is not returning the version of the assembly, but of the EXECUTING assembly, which in case of IIS ASP.NET are the web pages. You should not use GetExecuting Assembly if you want to have the version of a specific assembly. Grab a type in it (typeof) and get the assembly reference from there.

Comment: Have you tried `GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version`? [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyname.version?view=net-5.0)

Comment: You don't need to use reflection at all. Simply create a constant somewhere in your assembly and use its value both in your `getVersion` method and in AssemblyFileVersion attribute.

Comment: Steeeve - nah, single point of truth is better. then there would be 2 places where the version would live.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder It would be a single place - the constant you define. `class VersionInfo { const string VersionString="1.0.0.0";}` your method `string getVersion => VersionInfo.VersionString;` and in AssemblyInfo.cs `[AssemblyFileVersion(VersionInfo.VersionString)]`

Comment: Steeeve: I see. I like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultra-simple solution came from Steeeve:

Add new class:

```
public static class VersionInfo {
   public const string VersionString = "1.0";
}
```

Modify 2 lines of AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion(VersionInfo.VersionString)]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(VersionInfo.VersionString)]
```

And now anywhere else inside my DLL that needs to know its version at run time can simply call `VersionInfo.VersionString` and not need to resort to messy and expensive reflection.